# Integration over complex plane

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I have a problem with the following integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac {x\sin x}{x^4+1}$$

Can someone please help me with the way the solution goes? I would highly appreciate it

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first write the integral of interest as

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\sin x}{x^4+1}\,dx=\text{Im}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{xe^{ix}}{x^4+1}\,dx\right)\tag 1$$

Next, we analyze the contour integral

$$\oint_C \frac{ze^{iz}}{z^4+1}\,dz=\int_{-R}^R \frac{xe^{ix}}{x^4+1}\,dx+\int_0^\pi \frac{Re^{i\phi}e^{iRe^{i\phi}}}{R^4e^{i4\phi}+1}iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi \tag 2$$

As $R\to \infty$, the second integral in $(2)$ vanishes while the imaginary part of the first integral becomes the integral on the right-hand side $(1)$.  Therefore, we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\sin x}{x^4+1}\,dx=\text{Im}\left(2\pi i \sum \text{Res}\left(\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^4+1},z=e^{i\pi/4},e^{i3\pi/4}\right)\right)$$

The residues at $z=\frac{\pm1+i}{\sqrt 2}$ are given by

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to \frac{\pm1+i}{\sqrt 2}}\left(\frac{\left(z-\frac{\pm1+i}{\sqrt 2}\right)ze^{iz}}{z^4+1}\right)&=\lim_{z\to \frac{\pm1+i}{\sqrt 2}}\frac{e^{iz}}{4z^2}\\\\
&=\frac{e^{-1/\sqrt 2}e^{\pm i/\sqrt 2}}{\pm i4}
\end{align}$$

The sum of the residues is therefore

$$\frac12 e^{-1/\sqrt 2}\sin\left(1/\sqrt 2\right)$$

Putting it all together yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\sin x}{x^4+1}\,dx=\pi e^{-1/\sqrt 2}\sin\left(1/\sqrt 2\right)}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a few questions tho. Finding the poles, how did you find the residues? I probably make some mistake I couldnt work it out. You would have done me a great favour

Comment: I learning this anew so I am not comfortable with this yet

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I used L'Hospital's Rule to evaluate the limits used to calculate the residues.

Comment: Nice work (+1), alternativly write $x^ne^{ix}=(i)^a\partial^n_a e^{a ix}|_{a=1} $ to generate abritary powers of a in the nominator (as long as the integral converges)

Comment: @tired Thanks!  And yes.  That might have been even easier.